# Drilling into object sup-properties in v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

Basically I need to pass an object in as the value for all columns in my v-data-table.

For example instead of:

```
{
    name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
    calories: 237,
    fat: 9.0,
    carbs: 37
}
```

I need to set this as an example item in "items":

```
{
    name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
    calories: {value: 237, code: x},
    fat: {value: 9.0, code: y},
    carbs: {value: 37, code: z}
}
```

I know by using template I can still display just the value since I only want to display the value and not the code :

```
<div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="desserts"
            :page.sync="page"
            :items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
            hide-default-footer
            class="elevation-1"
            @page-count="pageCount = $event"
        >
            <template #item.calories="{item}">
                {{item.calories.value}}
            </template>
            <template #item.fat="{item}">
                {{item.fat.value}}
            </template>
            <template #item.carbs="{item}">
                {{item.carbs.value}}
            </template>
            <template #item.iron="{item}">
                {{item.iron.value}}
            </template>
        </v-data-table>
    </v-app>
</div>


<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      page: 1,
      pageCount: 0,
      itemsPerPage: 10,
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories'},
        { text: 'Fat', value: 'fat'},
        { text: 'Carb', value: 'carbs'},
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: {value: 159, score: 'x' },
          fat: {value: 80, score: 'y' },
          carbs: {value: 22, score: 'z' },
        }
      ]
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

My problem is that I will have many columns in my table and they are dynamic. (The "headers" and "items" are generated dynamically from server.) I would rather to not also generate a large number (30+) of these template conditions but I can't really see any other solution right now.

Comment: if you not found your solution, then, describe a little more, right now what you passed and then what is the output. after that what you want to output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `headers` prop's  `value` field for that. Vuetify **accepts property path** here:

```js
headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories.value'}, <-- HERE
        { text: 'Fat', value: 'fat.value'},
        { text: 'Carb', value: 'carbs.value'},
      ],
```